# datatable.merge don't add columns

Tags: c#, ado.net

```
Untyped DataTable
------------------
ColA ColB ColC

Typed DataTable
ColA ColB


TypedDataTable.Merge(UntypedDataTable)

Results in:

ColA ColB ColC
```

Is there anyway to keep it from adding the extra columns from untyped table?
In other words, I only want to keep ColA and ColB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Merge` has an overload that lets you specify what to do with missing schema.  One option is to ignore it, which should get the results you want.  See the MSDN article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtk78t63.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
bool preserveChanges = true;
```

> preserveChanges: true, to preserve changes in the current
>   System.Data.DataTable; otherwise false

```
TypedDataTable.Merge(UntypedDataTable, preserveChanges, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore)
```